# R:Compute many pvalues from pairwise t-test

Tags: r

I want to create a function in R that computes all (k choose 2) p-values from pairwise null hypotheses, using two-tailed t-tests.

The function would take two arguments, x and y, where x=a factor variable of k distinct levels, and y=a vector of real values. (x and y have same length).

And there are at least 2 (x,y) pairs for each distinct x-value.
 
My thought is that I should calculate the t value first, by calculating (m1-m2)/se, where se=sqrt(sd1*sd1/n1+sd2*sd2/n2)..And then calculate p-values by pt(-abs(t),df=pmin(n1,n2)-1..

Should I make some kind of a for-loop to calculate all of the p-values from each pair?

Since this is a "pval=function(x,y){#mycodehere}" function, I don't know how to go about doing such calculations for each pair.

Can anyone help me with this?!
 
Thanks so much!:)

Comment: You could check `combn` It would have been better if you provided a small example dataset.

Comment: `pairwise.t.test` already does this.

Comment: +1 for `pairwise.t.test`: it allows you to perform post-test corrections very easily too, which is really the way to go to avoid data dredging